# Have a shield spawn in with this mob

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here is the code for the mob:

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:zombie",CustomName:"EMPERIAL SHADOW GATE GUARDS",CustomNameVisible:1,Health:999,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:154},{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:1f},{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:0.6f},{Name:"generic.attackDamage",Base:9999},{Name:"zombie.spawnReinforcements",Base:1f}],Silent:1,Invulnerable:1,CanBreakDoors:1,HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:16,lvl:9999},{id:17,lvl:9999},{id:19,lvl:9999},{id:20,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999},{id:16,lvl:999}]},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:shield",tag:{ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:16,lvl:9999},{id:17,lvl:9999},{id:19,lvl:9999},{id:20,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999},{id:16,lvl:999}]},Count:1}],ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_boots",Count:1},{tag:{display:{Name:"shadow Imperial GATE GUARDS GEAR"},ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings",Count:1},{tag:{ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet",Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999}]}}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:3,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:5,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:10,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:12,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:13,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:21,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:22,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647}],Tags:["SHADOW EMPERIAL GATE GUARDS"],Team:Shadow}}
```

I'm trying to get this shield to spawn in with it:

```
/give @p minecraft:shield 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Base:0,Patterns:[{Color:1,Pattern:"cbo"},{Color:4,Pattern:"mr"},{Color:0,Pattern:"cbo"},{Color:0,Pattern:"bl"},{Color:0,Pattern:"tr"},{Color:0,Pattern:"mc"}]}}
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your command to the most important parts. Such a long command is extremely hard to understand.

Comment: Please specify what you want to do: Do you want to summon an item? Should the zombie hold it in his hand? Left or right? Main or second hand? Also: What resource did you use to get your long command?

Comment: I am trying to get a shield to spawn in the second hand and its something iv been working on for ages sorry and I cant figure this out

Comment: The reason why you're working on it for so long already is probably that you're making it hard for yourself: First try to summon a zombie that holds something in his offhand. Then give tags to the item. Then make a spawn egg that spawns this zombie. And then add all your other tags back in.

Answer (score 2):

You have actually done most of the work.

Lets look specifically at the shield portion of the original command:

```
{id:"minecraft:shield",tag:{ench:[...]},Count:1}
```

We want to add `BlockEntityTag` data to that:

```
{id:"minecraft:shield",tag:{BlockEntityTag:{...},ench:[...]},Count:1}
```

You can copy and paste the `BlockEntityTag` data from the second command into the first command.  Paste right after `tag:{` and remember to add a comma after.

The command from doing that is:

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:zombie",CustomName:"EMPERIAL SHADOW GATE GUARDS",CustomNameVisible:1,Health:999,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:154},{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:1f},{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:0.6f},{Name:"generic.attackDamage",Base:9999},{Name:"zombie.spawnReinforcements",Base:1f}],Silent:1,Invulnerable:1,CanBreakDoors:1,HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:16,lvl:9999},{id:17,lvl:9999},{id:19,lvl:9999},{id:20,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999},{id:16,lvl:999}]},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:shield",tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:0,Patterns:[{Color:1,Pattern:"cbo"},{Color:4,Pattern:"mr"},{Color:0,Pattern:"cbo"},{Color:0,Pattern:"bl"},{Color:0,Pattern:"tr"},{Color:0,Pattern:"mc"}]},ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:16,lvl:9999},{id:17,lvl:9999},{id:19,lvl:9999},{id:20,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999},{id:16,lvl:999}]},Count:1}],ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_boots",Count:1},{tag:{display:{Name:"shadow Imperial GATE GUARDS GEAR"},ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings",Count:1},{tag:{ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet",Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:2,lvl:9999},{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:9999},{id:3,lvl:9999},{id:4,lvl:9999},{id:7,lvl:9999},{id:9,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:9999},{id:71,lvl:9999}]}}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:3,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:5,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:10,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:12,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:13,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:21,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647},{Id:22,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647}],Tags:["SHADOW EMPERIAL GATE GUARDS"],Team:Shadow}}
```

This gives an egg which yields this guy:
[image: Zombie]

Answer (score -1):

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"\"Tier 100 Zombie\"",CustomNameVisible:1,Health:50,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:50},{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:226},{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:0.23f},{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:4.7f},{Name:"generic.attackDamage",Base:7},{Name:"zombie.spawnReinforcements",Base:0.61f}],IsBaby:0,HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:netherite_axe",tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"the best weapon"}',Lore:['{"text":"not really lol"}']},Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:5}]},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:shield",tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"yes"}',Lore:['{"text":"no"}']},Enchantments:[{id:unbreaking,lvl:3}]},Count:1}],HandDropChances:[0.47F,0F],ArmorItems:[{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_boots",Count:1},{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings",Count:1},{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet",Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4}]}}]}
```

Comment: Hey hhs, welcome to Arqade. Take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't yet and if in need of guidance please read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help). You should avoid one-line answer, even if the command is right. You should complete your answer with an explanation of how your answer fix the OPs problem.